# Is there a name and function for this graph

Tags: graphing-functions

First of all, I am not very good at math, and I am a programmer who develops (web)applications

I was working on a web-app which is used for training on a stationary bike, it is used with smart bikes of which the resistance can be controlled.

What I needed to build was a way to keep the output wattage within a range.

I have solved this in code by increasing and decreasing the value of the resistance around the min and max values.

Here is a crudely drawn graph of what it does.

[image: Graph]

Is there an equation which would plot this graph with the min and max values as the input?

And what would you call this graph with the 2 exponential curves?

Sorry if this question is unclear, or if this is not the correct place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution.

Let $[m,n]$ be the [min,max] interval in which you want a flat part.

Take the following function:

$$\begin{cases}y&=&a+b \left(\sin(\ell(x)) - \ell(x)\right) \ \text{where}\\ \ell(x)&=&c \frac{2x-(m+n)}{n-m}\end{cases}$$

based on the "mother function" $y=\sin(x)-x$ with parameters allowing to modulate the curve in different ways : height, width, etc. ; one can take for example $a=5,b=1,c=1$ at the beginning.

[image]

**Edit:** Have a look at the green curve with parametric equations:

$$\begin{cases}x(t)&=&8-1.5t+\sin(t)\\y(t)&=&7+t+\sin(t)
\end{cases}$$

that can maybe constitute a better basis for answering your issue.

Linear algebra remark:

This type of curve is obtained as an image of the "mother sine" curve by the following affine transform:

$$\pmatrix{x(t)\\y(t)}=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{t\\ sin(t)}+\pmatrix{e\\f}$$

for certain well-chosen coefficients $a,b,...f$.

Comment: Nice. But I think the OP wants another inflection point so that the curve starts out cap shaped.

Comment: Great, this is definitely what I was looking for! Thank you. @EthanBolker, yes I do want the curve to have a cap at the start, but I actually want it to act different for when the value for the x axis is increased from below the min value or when coming from above the min value.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker In fact, due to the periodicity of sine function, one has this "cap shape" on the left.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes. You or the OP will have to shift to make it appear.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Done. Please see the edit I have added.